# Developing iPhone, Android and Windows Phone apps using C# on Ubuntu

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone-7, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu on my home computer (however have access to a Macbook Air) and am learning `C#` (using Visual Studio at school).

There is a mobile phone app I would like to make, which I am confident can be done with my skill set for Windows, however it is not in the course to transfer these applications to a mobile device.

So firstly what programs would I be best to use to create programs for the above OS in that order of importance using `C# on Ubuntu?` I would like to do the programming on the Ubuntu desktop but can publish from the Mac. Also what do I need to do in order to transfer my programs to a mobile OS? Mostly needs to support reading and writing to a file, zooming and would late like to add `GPS location` and access to `weather`.

I hope I have provided enough detail for you to assist, for now I'd just like to get started and will most likely have specifics later.
Thank you.

Comment: Look into using [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/) which lets you use _most_ features of C# and a good chunk of the .NET BCL. Separate your business/core logic code from your GUI layer, then you can share that business/core code across all 3 platforms. (Windows Phone development though I'm not sure if you can do on Ubuntu; may need to dual/virtual boot into Windows with Visual Studio. Not sure about that.)

Comment: I do have windows 8 with visual studio installed on a hard drive but the install decided to corrupt itself, easily remedied though. Would the read and write coding be the same across platforms? The search will be shared. The GUI is very simple though. Basically it is to save a picture with a setup saved to it so when the user clicks a point on the picture it shows up a text box. Thanks

Comment: Reading/writing to the phone is likely slightly different between all 3 platforms (though Xamarin might expose the same API calls, there could be minor quirks in terms of locations/paths/permissions). Just throw in a quick layer of abstraction if necessary. Figure out what aspects of your code will be interfacing with the phone and test them specifically to see how to do it for each platform.